# What is wrong with this Jquery Post Query?

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-3, post, razor

I have one Jquery Post Query. After sending the request to the controller action its not getting the control to proceed further. Actually, I am doing this action on button click through the Button Id. I am just posting the code here. Please suggest me where i am doing wrong.

**View Code**

```
    $('#Get').click(function () {
    ItemNo= "4";
    if (ItemNo != "" && ItemNo != '') {
            $.post('@Url.Action("CheckStocktake", "Stocktake")', { ItemNo: ItemNo }, function (data) {

                if (data == "I") {
                    $('#ItemNumber').after("<label class='label' id='inoitem' style='color:red;float:right;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;Item No is not exist in the Items table entry.</label>");
                    e.preventDefault();
                    return false;
                }
                else if (data == "S") {
                    $('#ItemNumber').after("<label class='label' id='inostock' style='color:red;float:right;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;Entered Item No. already exist in Stocktake. Try another.</label>");
                    e.preventDefault();
                    return false;
                }
                else if (data == "F") {
                    alert("");
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
```

**Controller Code**

```
      public JsonResult CheckStocktake(string ItemNo)
    {
        bool ifexist = Db.Items.Any(a => a.ItemNo == ItemNo);
        bool stockexist = Db.Stocktakes.Any(b => b.ItemNo == ItemNo);
        if (!ifexist)
        {
            return Json("I", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else if (stockexist)
        {
            return Json("S", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        return Json("F", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);


    }
```

Comment: Check the console (press `F12`) - do you see any errors from the AJAX call?

Comment: Have you tried changing the `ItemNo` parameter to `id`?

Comment: Actually Its allowing to form post even its not coming down to the returned function(data).

Comment: Yes I tried changing ItemNo parameter. But No use.

Comment: Try adding `[HttpPost]` before `public JsonResult CheckStocktake(string ItemNo)`

Comment: Try using Fiddler to see what, if any, data is being returned. It could be it hitting the success function but it is not in the format you are expecting. Your code in the success function does not handle the condition where it is not what is expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(data, function (index, d)
{
    place your if conditions inside this changing data to d.......
}
```

hope it may work, if not try changing your call to below....

```
$.getJSON("/Controller/action", { ItemNo: ItemNo }, function (data)
         {
             $.each(data, function (index, d) 
            {
                if condition here as i mentioned above change data to d
            });

        });
```

it should work let me know ...whats going on